# Persian Calendar not valid with CultureInfo

Tags: c#, calendar, cultureinfo

What's wrong with this code?

Error(Exception) message :

> Not a valid calendar for the given culture.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-Ir"); //Error
ci.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
Application.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

And what's its solution?
Can I add a `Calendar` type to Windows XP regional option?

Comment: There is some information about the problems with Persian calendar [in MSDN (see bottom of the page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx). Maybe it can help a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a dirty reflection-based workaround is here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4768d48e-aa04-4c15-b688-a58fa4373bc9/

Answer (score 3):

It is explicitly mentioned in the MSDN article for PersianCalendar

> Your application should not use a
>   PersianCalendar object as the default
>   calendar for a culture. The default
>   calendar is specified by the
>   CultureInfo.Calendar property and
>   must be one of the calendars returned
>   by the
>   CultureInfo.OptionalCalendars
>   property. Currently, the
>   PersianCalendar class is not an
>   optional calendar for any culture
>   supported by the CultureInfo class and
>   consequently cannot be a default
>   calendar.

You cannot make this work.  Use the Calendar as-is.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new culture type in Windows XP regional and Language options in control Panel?

Comment: No, you cannot fix this no matter what you try.

Comment: So,Is there any solution that help me to use VS controls(such as datetimepicker) with persian calendar in my application projects?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  Start a new one.

Comment: if i add persian calendar in regional option i guess i can use it for this purpose, so it's the same question. but i will start new one:)